# If mysql value contains another mysql value from a different table, echo

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, "customers" and "users".

In the customers table, I have a column titled "name". This has all customer names.

In my users table, I have a column titled "managing". This has certain customer names.

I am trying to display content if "managing" *CONTAINS* **ANY** customer from "name".

Here is an example...

"name" contains customers "applebees", "johnny carinos", and "pizza hut".

User rick is "managing" "applebees" and "pizza hut". In his row/the column, it looks like "applebees,pizza hut" (i am using the implode function which is why there is a ,")

So, on my customers page, I want rick to see applebees and pizza hut. I do NOT want to him to see johnny carinos, since he isn't managing it.

How can I do this? I've tried preg match & strpos but failed miserably. (I'm still rather new to php). This would be much easier of it was a single value, so I can just set value = value. Unfortunately, having multiple values for "managing" really messes me up!

Hope this made sense. Thanks for any help!

Here's what I have now (yes, i know, it's terribly wrong, probably.)

```
<?php


$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
        $thecust = $_SESSION['user']['managing'];
    $thecustomers = htmlentities($row['name']);


    $check = strprk(wing, $thecust);
    if ($check) {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

    <tr> 
        <td><?php echo "<a href='customer.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</a>"?></td> 
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['contact_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['contact_number'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['contact_email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
    </tr> 

<? } ?>
```

Comment: Do you only need to show the data for "Rick"?  In the big picture rick is logged in and he needs to see the properties he is managing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in your database schema and the way you query it.  You didn't really get into your DB table structure but I would propose you use something like this

```
users
-------
user_id INT, autoincrement, PRIMARY KEY
user_name VARCHAR
[other user-specific fields]

users_to_customers
-------
user_id INT
customer_id INT
[compound primary key across both fields]

customers
-------
customer_id INT, autoincrement, PRIMARY KEY
customer_name VARCHAR
[other customer specific fields]
```

Note I have three tables here.  This allows you to relate any number of users to any number of customers.  NOw to get teh information you are looking for, let's assume you know the `user_id` of the user viewing the customers page.  You query might look like

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name, [whatever other fields you need]
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN users_to_customers AS uc
INNER JOIN customers AS c
WHERE u.user_id = ? [the user_id of the user viewing the page]
```

This will give you customer information for those customers related to the the user.

---

You also should not be using the `mysql_*` functions are they are deprecated (note the big red warning in PHP.net documentation). perhaps use mysqli_* functions.

Comment: Brilliant! I will go ahead and implement this sometime tonight and report back if I have done so successfully and mark your answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex Just updated to include information about how the primary keys should be set up on these tables.

Comment: When creating new customers/users, I suppose I would run a second query to also create a new id in users_to_customers so that all the id's match up among the three tables, correct? Or is there a more efficient method to do this?

Comment: @Alex That is correct. Also if there isn't a many to many relationship between users and customers (i.e there is one-to-many relationship between users and customers) then you could do away with the `users_to_customers` table and put a `user_id` field directly in `customers` to represent the user who manages that customer.

Comment: About to implement your solution here...when the user has assigned customers, it looks like this: `Winghouse,Red Hot & Blue,Applebees`. So, your code still only will display those customers and not other customers, correct? I ask this because the customer names would obviously not match up to the field that lists the customers managed for a user since that field has all the customers in one. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Don't use comma separated values as your field values. If he user has relations to 3 customers, then there should be 3 records in the user to customer table each with the users I'd and one each with the I'd of each customer.